# IntersectionObserver sets isIntersecting property of all elements to true on initial load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Yesterday I ran this code and everything worked as intended. The `observer` loaded in the images when they were intersecting the viewport:

```
<template>
  <div id="gallery" class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-card">
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/1.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/ph.png" data-src="../../images/2.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/ph.png" data-src="../../images/3.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/ph.png" data-src="../../images/4.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/ph.png" data-src="../../images/5.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/ph.png" data-src="../../images/6.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import {onMounted} from "vue";

onMounted(() => {
    let config = {
        rootMargin: '0px 0px 50px 0px',
        threshold: 0
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, self) {
        console.log(entries)
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if(entry.isIntersecting) {
                const img = entry.target
                img.src = img.dataset.src
                self.unobserve(img);
            }})
    }, config);

    const lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll('[data-src]');

    lazyImages.forEach(img => {
        console.log(img.src)
        observer.observe(img);
    });
})

</script>
```

But today the `IntersectionObserver` loads in all images at once during initial page load. I've tried to debug this with `console.log()` and the weird thing is that the correct `img` element is passed to the `observer`:

```
const lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll('[data-src]');
lazyImages.forEach(img => {
    console.log(img.src)
    observer.observe(img);
});
```

Output (x5, placeholder image):

```
http://localhost:3000/images/ph.png?3d03f427893c28791c9e0b8a347a277d
```

but the `observer` seems to receive an initial `entries` object with all `isIntersecting` properties set to `true`, which then loads in all images:

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, self) {
    console.log(entries)
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            const img = entry.target
            img.src = img.dataset.src
            self.unobserve(img);
        }
    })
}, config);
```

Output:

[image]

Any way I can prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a really late response. But anyway I'll share some ideas that could be helpful.

```
 rootMargin: '0px 0px 50px 0px',
 threshold: 0
```

that would be "use the viewport as root, consider a 50px bottom margin below the viewport's bottom (see [this image to understand rootMargin](https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/769b2733-5700-4d2d-a32f-6850a173abaa/1-dynamic-header-intersection-observer.png)).

What can be happening is that all your images are in fact already visible on the initial load, so all images **are** being intersected.

I had a similar problem with a custom *scrollspy* implementation but with the `!isIntersecting` condition. Solved it using a *boolean* flag that starts on `false` in order to catch the initial load, and it's set to `true` when the scrolling begins.

In your case, I think changing the:

```
if (entry.isIntersecting) {
```

line to:

```
if (entry.isIntersecting && startedIntersecting) {
```

would solve the initial intersecting problem.

This piece of code  captures the first scroll, sets the flag to true and stops capturing the scroll event, leaving all the rest to the IntersectionObserver.

For this I used RxJS's [fromEvent](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent) like this:

```
startedIntersecting = false;

fromEvent(document, 'scroll').pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  distinctUntilChanged(), 
  takeWhile(() => startedIntersecting !== true)
).subscribe($evt => {
  console.log('startedIntersecting', $evt);
  startedIntersecting = true;
});
```

Hope it enlightens things a bit.